# Ability to define that at least 1 of N attributes are required?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Does JSONSchema have the ability to define that at least 1 of N attributes should be required?

Something like:

`required: anyOf(["x", "y"])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `anyOf` in combination with `required`:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "anyOf": [
        {"required": ["x"]},
        {"required": ["y"]},
        ...
    ]
}
```